# memcpy () : Access violation writing location

Tags: exception, memory, segmentation-fault, memcpy

I am getting Access violation writing location 0xB7066CBC while running this code.Unable to figure out whats going on, any suggestions?

```
int main(void)

{
unsigned int SIG = 0x00000000;
unsigned int *base = (unsigned int *)0xb7066CBC;
SIG = 0x5a5a5a5a;
memcpy(base ,&SIG, 4);
}
```

Here are the values I am getting when I encounter this failure.

```
&SIG 0x003bf7c0 {0x5a5a5a5a}
SIG  0x5a5a5a5a
base 0xb7066cbc {???}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am getting Access violation writing location `0xB7066CBC` while running this code.Unable to figure out whats going on

What's going on is that the 4 bytes at location `0xB7066CBC` are not writable.

Your problem most likely lies in whatever reasoning led you to believe that these bytes *are* (or should be) writable, but since you didn't provide any clue as to what that reasoning might be, it's hard to offer any help.

Comment: Got it. That memory location is processor specific and has to run on a different environment than my local machine. Thanks the above exploitation helped.